# Android camera error while connecting to camera 0

Tags: android, android-camera, qr-code

I have a really weird problem. When I install app from scratch (wipe data is made before), after giving all permission, functionality with camera opens and works like a charm. But when I decide to go to other parts of app and then go back to this camera functionality this error always occures. Camera release, stop preview and all the neccessary methods are called. What's interesting I created new blank project and I gave all the manifest permission, checked permissions in code and so on and this error does not exists anymore. I can go anywhere I want in the app and then go back to qr code reader and this error never occures.

The functionality is simple qr code reader from here:

`https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner`

`W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8): '10: connectHelper:1396: Failed to initialize camera "0": Function not implemented (-38)'`

Any ideas?

Comment: This could be a delicate timing problem: the physical camera may need some time to respond to the commands. ¶

The basic rule is that the calls to camera API *may fail*. Sensitive sequences of camera API calls should be wrapped in `try…catch`, and it's legitimate to try the same sequence again if it failed.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this also do not help. I tried to try/catch everyting what was possible. On real devices app started to work but on emulators behaviour is still the same.

Comment: Emulators are of almost no value for actual camera-related development. [They say](https://developer.android.com/preview/features#camera-emulator) that on Android R they finally made the camera code on emulator to do many things the same way as on real device, but I didn't have a chance to prove this claim.